# Importing Facebook data (education and experience) from facebook

Tags: php, fbconnect

I want to allow users to import their Facebook education and experience entries into a job board site. Something like this site does 
http://www.jobster.com/at/person/edit_profile
(see the FB icon on the right, under the sign in form)

Do they simply use the good old FB Connect to achieve that or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)

`user_education_history` and `user_work_history` are what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I know about them, I worked with FB connect before. It's just when I connected to the site above, I didn't notice any questions like "the site requires additional permissions, is it ok to grant them?". But actually I could have overlooked that question. FB is acting up right now so I'll reconnect my profile later and will try to find anything about permissions when I connect to that site.